# Multiple Background Images Using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how to position multiple background images with CSS3. I'm not doing so well. How do you get an image to position at the top of the page, in the middle of the page and at the bottom of the page? Let's just use a 100px x 100px block for illustration purposes. I can only get them to position along the top.

CSS

```
body {
background-image: 
url(../images/red.png), 
url(../images/blue.png), 
url(../images/yellow.png);
background-position: left top, center top, right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I want them left top, left center and then left bottom.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your tags.

```
body {
    background-image: 
        url(../images/red.png) left top no-repeat, 
        url(../images/blue.png) center top no-repeat,, 
        url(../images/yellow.png) right top no-repeat, 
}
```

Edit:

```
<style type="text/css"> 

    background-image: 
    url(../images/red.png),  
    url(../images/yellow.png);
    background-position: left top, left bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    #centerIMG {
        margin-top:-50px;
        height: 100px;
        width:  100px;
        background:url(../images/blue.png) center left no-repeat;
    }
    #outer {height: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
    #outer[id] {display: table; position: static;}

    #middle {position: absolute; top: 50%;} /* for explorer only*/
    #middle[id] {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;}

    #inner {position: relative; top: -50%} /* for explorer only */
</style>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="middle">
            <div id="inner">
                <div id="centerIMG"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    body
    {
        background:
            url("red.png") top repeat-x,
            url("blue.png") bottom repeat-x,
            url("orange.png") center repeat;

            background-size: 200px, 100px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't want all three to be along the top. I want them left top, left center and then left bottom.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, I missed that cause you had top in all three. "center right no-repeat" gets it centered, but using the baseline of the image. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Forgot to mention, you only have to modify "#centerIMG". The code centers the div, to get the image centered you just set the margin to "minus (half image height)" as I have for the example.

Comment: I tried your examples and I don't know what it is that you are trying to do for me.

Comment: The code will vertically align in center "../images/blue.png". All you need to do is change the height, width and magin in #centerIMG.

Comment: I know how to create a div and place a background image inside of it. This is so far from what I was asking.

Comment: I believe it's what you were after. "../images/red.png" is left top, "../images/blue.png" is left center, "../images/yellow.png" is left bottom. What was it I missed?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8746/discussion-between-bradley-forster-and-ibanez)